# Set a default Value of a UIPickerView: index beyond bounds

Tags: swift, uipickerview

I am trying to set default value for PickerView element but there is an error when running: index beyond the bonds, My intention is to star from "Difficult" option as default, that is, nivel = 3.

```
@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.spinner.delegate = self
    self.spinner.dataSource = self
    nivel = 3
    lista_parametros = ["All","Easy","Medium","Dificult"]
    self.spinner.selectRow(4, inComponent: nivel, animated: true) /// the error is here !! when running 
}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return lista_parametros.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
     return lista_parametros[row]
 }

 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
     nivel = row
     UserDefaults.standard.set(nivel,forKey: "nivel")
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index starts from `0`. So you should modify it to this:

```
spinner.selectRow(3, inComponent: nivel, animated: true)
```

Comment: ok, now when I first open this activity it is ok the spinner correctly opens at difficult position , but if I select another position in this spinner (for example I manually adjust them to easy) and then open it again this activity, then the same error occur

Comment: How do I select an index if I use TextFeidld with UIPickerView?

Answer (score 1):

The selection must be made at first parameter:

```
self.spinner.selectRow(nivel, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```